# Exchange server to sync accounts with Small Business server

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs

We have a server with SBS 2003 that carries all our users. We're looking to set up a separate server for exchange 2010. Is there a way to keep these in constant sync so that when I set up an account on SBS 2003, that it will set up the same account information for the exchange 2010 server?

Comment: I removed your Sharepoint tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Exchange requires Active Directory to work. When you setup the new server, you will add it to your domain as a member server. When you install Exchange, it will be integrated with AD. You will create mailboxes in Exchange Management Console, and associate them with AD user accounts.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I was thinking along that route - just needed the specific terms.